# VB.NET Web Service - Returning ReadOnly Properties from Inherited Class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I assume I am missing something very basic, but here is my plight.  In VB.net, I have created a class that inherits `MembershipUser` and returns the object from a web service:

```
Public Class ModifiedUser
    Inherits MembershipUser
```

*The user logs in:*

```
Private Sub Login1_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles Login1.Authenticate
    Dim ws As New MembersWS.Members
    Dim Member As New MembersWS.ModifiedUser
    ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials()
    Member = ws.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password)
End Sub
```

When the object is created in the web service, `ModifiedUser` contains all of the properties of `MembershipUser` as well as the properties of the new class.

In my example, the `ValidateUser` function validates the user and adds the additional properties:

```
Public Function ValidateUser(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As ModifiedUser
    Dim BaseUser As MembershipUser = Membership.Provider.GetUser(UserName, False)
    Dim Member As New ModifiedUser
    If Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(UserName, Password) = True Then 
        Member = New ModifiedUser(BaseUser.ProviderName, BaseUser.UserName, BaseUser.ProviderUserKey, BaseUser.Email, BaseUser.PasswordQuestion, BaseUser.Comment, BaseUser.IsApproved, BaseUser.IsLockedOut, BaseUser.CreationDate, BaseUser.LastLoginDate, BaseUser.LastActivityDate, BaseUser.LastPasswordChangedDate, BaseUser.LastLockoutDate, 0, "", "", "", "", True)
        ' ... (Set new property values)
    End if
    Return Member
End Function
```

When `Member` is returned to `Login1_Authenticate`, the readonly properties are dropped from the object while they were included in the object being returned from the web service.

In the `reference.vb` file for the web service, the auto-generated code includes a partial `MembershipUser` class including only the updateable properties with the associated getters and setters:

```
Partial Public Class MembershipUser
    Private emailField As String
    Private commentField As String
    Private isApprovedField As Boolean
    Private lastLoginDateField As Date
    Private lastActivityDateField As Date
```

**If anyone can let me know how to include the readonly properties in the returned object, I'd really appreciate it.**

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow!  Please review the edits I made so you can see how you should better format your questions and answers in the future.

Comment: As Steven mentioned, make use of the code tags to display the right formatting for your source code.

Comment: @Dayan You seem to have made it worse :)

Comment: @Dayan Well, you added unnecessary blank lines, which, while that's more a personal preference thing, I think in these stack overflow posts, it's helpful to keep the code samples shorter so you don't have to scroll as much.  But the "more worse" thing that you did was you messed up the indentation of the beginning and ending lines of the methods, etc. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a web service returns an object that contains read-only properties, the read-only properties are always ignored.  That is because on the client-side, it would not be able to deserialize the data by setting the value of the read-only property.  One way to fix this is to add a setter to your property which does nothing or throws an exception.  For instance:

```
Public Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return nID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        Throw New Exception("Cannot set read-only property 'Id'")
    End Set
End Property
```

See this question for more ideas:

[Is it possible to create read only elements in SOAP web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915672/is-it-possible-to-create-read-only-elements-in-soap-web-services)

Comment: Steven, thanks for the editing tips and the answer!  Does this mean I have to set up additional properties and pass the values of the read-only properties to them since I can't override the existing read-only properties while including a setter?  Basically, I need an additional property for the returned web service object for each read-only property in the MembershipUser class.  Am I on the right track or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Yes, outside of writing your own custom serialization logic, I think adding new non-read-only properties in the derived class is probably the best way to go.  The getter could just return the base class' read-only property and the setter could throw an exception or do nothing.